# Do i have to mutex a reading operation while other threads are writing thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

i am confused in a specific multithreading situation and couldn´t find clear explanations to this scenario. In the code below two custom threads are writing+reading thread safe but the main thread is also reading concurrently. So here is my question: Do i have to mutex the read function, too? Or is it absolutly impossible to crash the app maybe cause of previously deleted pointers in the vector for example? I hope you guys can help me, Thanks!

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int g_i = 0;
std::vector<int> test;
std::mutex g_i_mutex;  // protects g_i

void safe_increment()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
    ++g_i;
    test.resize(test.size() + 1, 2);
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << g_i << '\n';

    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " thread vector: " << *i << '\n';
    // g_i_mutex is automatically released when lock
    // goes out of scope
}


void request_threadedvar()
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " request threaded vector: " << *i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main: " << g_i << '\n';
    test.resize(test.size() + 1, 1);
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << "main vector: " << *i << '\n';

    std::thread t1(safe_increment);
    request_threadedvar();
    std::thread t2(safe_increment);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "main: " << g_i << '\n';
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << "main vector: " << *i << '\n';

}
```

Comment: If any thread is writing to shared data, any reading of that shared data experiences a race condition.   So, yes, the `main()` function and the "read function" need to use the mutex, if there is at least one (potentially) active writer.     If there is a guarantee of no active writing but only reading (for example, the writer teminates before any reader threads start, and no more writers are created) then the readers would not need to synchronise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `std::thread` execution threads, as well as the original `main` execution thread are invoking various methods of the same `std::vector` object.

None of `std::vector`'s methods (or any of the C++ library containers' methods) are thread-safe, so all access to them from all execution threads must be sequenced (i.e. protected by a mutex). It doesn't matter whether the vector's contents are modified, or not. `begin()` is not thread safe. Full stop. Etc...

Adding insult to injury, `resize()` invalidates all existing iterators to the contents of a `std::vector`, so a `resize()` that gets executed by any of the `std::thread`s will immediately invalidate all iterators to the same `std::vector` object in use by the other threads; and thusly the whole thing must be sequenced/locked.

TL;DR: you must use a mutex for any access to a `std::vector`. Whether the contents of the vector are modified, or not, by a particular execution thread, is immaterial.

P.S. The issue of `std::vector` methods not being thread safe is independent of the thread-safety of whatever's in the vector. If you already have all the iterators to the vector's contents ready, and start doing things to what's in the vector using the existing iterators in multiple execution threads: whether that requires sequencing depends on the inherent nature of whatever's in your vector, and its thread-safety requirements.

Comment: First of all thanks for this explanation! So if i add a lock to the read function of the main thread the iterator is always safe/valid? And the above code is fully thread safe?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "*It doesn't matter whether the vector's contents are modified, or not.*": `const` methods and some others including `begin()` are guaranteed to be data race free if called from multiple threads. So really everything is fine as long as no thread is potentially modifying the vector at the same time. (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#container.requirements.dataraces-1) Of course, here modification happens, so the mutex lock is required everywhere. I just thought the way you wrote it may be misinterpreted.

Comment: Yes. The rule of thumb is that all access to the vector must be protected by a mutex lock.